# find radius of freehand drawn circle using android onDraw()

Tags: android, center, draw, geometry

i have to draw circle with free hand in `onDraw()` method.
After drawing the circle, i have to find the radius and center of that circle and show that circle again with `drawCircle()` method.

Can anyone help me to find the radius and center of circle with free hand drawing.

Comment: how do you do the drawing circle with free hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the center as the average of all the points on the edge.
And the diameter as the largest distance between any two points.

Or once you have the center, find the distance between each edge point and the point across from it. Then average these.